# Generate C File Stream Object on remote machine without fopen()

Tags: c, file-access

Let's say we have an elf `a` and a textfile `a.txt` in the same directory.
The `a` elf is a program, that is remotely accessible/executable.
In addition `a` contains the instruction `fgets(buf,len,stdin);` and a remote attacker manages to get full control over the stdin object. Is the attacker able to reliably generate a file stream object pointing to `a.txt`? It should be the equivalent to the object generated by `fopen("a.txt","r");`. If yes, how would he do that?

Answer (score 1):

If by "full control over the stdin object" you mean provide stdin input to `a`, then this depends on the size and location of `buf`, the memory layout of `a`, and what `len` is. In this case, the way you pose your question does not provide enough information to answer this.

If you mean corrupting the pointers in the `struct FILE`, then yes, usually it is possible. Unless the file descriptor of `a.txt` is already present in the target process, it's unfortunately not as easy as overwriting the file descriptor and clearing the buffers in the `struct FILE`. It is however usually possible to gain arbitrary code execution by overwriting the stream buffer pointers and writing to `stdin`, which gives you a write-what-where primitive. The precise overwrite targets again depend on the target executable.

For a detailed discussion of a similar exploit technique, see the "Play with FILE structure" HITBGSEC 18 talk ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fr3VU5hdL4s)/[slides](https://gsec.hitb.org/materials/sg2018/D1%20-%20FILE%20Structures%20-%20Another%20Binary%20Exploitation%20Technique%20-%20An-Jie%20Yang.pdf)/[whitepaper](https://gsec.hitb.org/materials/sg2018/WHITEPAPERS/FILE%20Structures%20-%20Another%20Binary%20Exploitation%20Technique%20-%20An-Jie%20Yang.pdf)).